# Work item customization: Changing the default date/time format from into date time format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: customization

My problem is that I need to change the date time format (5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM) into date time format (2020/05/01) on  a Work Item's custom field. We do not want time numbers.

Is that possible? What type of setting is it?

Thank you,